# Letting the user wait for shorten a link?

Tags: social-media, response-time, sharing, loading

I have an application where I show a list of news. These news can be shared by the user (simple share-intent you can see in almost every android-application). However, I don't want the user to send the whole link, because these links sometimes can become pretty large. So what I'm doing is to shorten the url by sending an http-request to a shortener-service. This can take 5-10 seconds to get the response.

I'm currently shorten every single url in my news-feed (~10-30 per feed). This is a huge amount and I don't want my user to have 30 http requests for every feed (well it's in the background, he doesn't notice it, but still it consumes network-traffic).

So what I thought is to shorten only the url which is intended to be shared. But therefore the user must wait until the application gets the response of the server, which is also not what the user wants...

Any ideas how to solve this in a good way? Should I maybe ask the user before sharing if he wants to shorten the link (and letting him know that it takes some amount of time) or should I just continue loading the shortened-urls in the background?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create the shortened URL when you publish the article, and add it as the link to share, there would be no need to wait for a service to create it. Secondly, you don't have to shorten it each time it's shared, since it is shortened the first time the service is used. You could possibly run into trouble with the URL shorten service if your page is shared a lot and you try to generate a new URL on each share request,

Comment: What do you mean by "when you publush the article" ? I don't publish the articles, the summaries of an article are downloaded within a rss-feed-file. In addition, I'm already caching the shortened-link - means, wherever I shorten the link, it will be saved and reused if you share the article again - but the question is still: Where should I shorten the link, before sharing, directly after I got the rss-feed or at another point in time

Comment: @Frame91 Nice that you cache it. The answer is, as soon as you possibly can and then cache it.